# Why are the write(..) methods java.io.Writer synchronized?

Tags: java, multithreading, file-io, io, filewriter

I am using java.io.FileWriter to write some data to the disk.
As you know, FileWriter extends OutputStreamWriter, which in turn extends Writer.

When I looked at Writer's write(..), to my amazement it is synchronized.

```
**java.io.Writer**

    public void write(int c) throws IOException {
        synchronized (lock) {
            if (writeBuffer == null){
                writeBuffer = new char[WRITE_BUFFER_SIZE];
            }
            writeBuffer[0] = (char) c;
            write(writeBuffer, 0, 1);
        }
    }
```

I am curious as to why the writes are synchronized in the base Writer class?
For my use case, I only have one writer thread and have absolutely no need for writes(..) to be synchronized.

I am aware that acquiring un-contended locks are much faster than contended locks. However, this whole business of having the base Writer class synchronized doesn't look like a good design to me.

Is there an un-synchronized Writer class that I have missed?

Thanks

Comment: I can understand the astonishment, but if you have a single writer thread, then it does not make much of a difference in practice, does it? My question being, are you asking out of curiosity, or are you trying to achieve some particular objective that I may have missed?

Comment: Since Java 6 there is [escape analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_performance#Escape_analysis_and_lock_coarsening) applied, so locks which can never be contended aren't acquired. As such, it often won't hurt that it is synchronized in the source code, and might avoid concurrency bugs you weren't expecting in other cases.

Comment: For people who use multiple threads, this is very much a must. For people who don't use multiple threads, since uncontested locks take up a lot less time than the writing itself (I/O is generally an order of magnitude slower), it's negligible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am curious as to why the writes are synchronized in the base Writer class?

This implementation will work correctly whether you need it to be thread safe or not.  This means it will work with the widest range of use cases.

> For my use case, I only have one writer thread and have absolutely no need for writes(..) to be synchronized.

If you only ever lock an object using the same thread each time, it will do this very efficiently (if you have biased locking enabled which is the default)

> Is there an un-synchronized Writer class that I have missed?

It has a very small overhead which you can measure in CPU bound tasks but it will be around 1/1000th the delay of the actual write to IO. i.e. you won't be able to tell the difference for you use case.

Comment: Hi Peter, thank you for your comments. I would have left Writer as un-synchronized and added a synchronized version on top of it and let the users choose. I agree regarding acquiring uncontended lock being fast however this wasn't always the case and further it will never be faster than the un-synchronized version (if they had one).